# IE7 hangs on my site build in asp.net 3.5

Tags: javascript

Whenever I open a new window with javascript like this:

```
function openwindow(){
window.open(blah blah)
}
```

on my masterpage my IE7 browser hangs.The new window is a chatroom page built in ajax controltoolkit and a music playlist for a user to listen to his/her created playlist.The problem only occurs in IE7 but ok on other browsers such as firefox,safari,google chrome,or opera....anybody knows? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I had / have the same problem.  I found this link that explains things...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx

"Internet Explorer 7 on Windows Vista: Opening a new window from an application (other than the Internet Explorer process) may result in a null return value. This restriction occurs because Internet Explorer runs in protected mode by default. One facet of protected mode prevents applications from having priveledged access to Internet Explorer when that access spans process boundaries. Opening a new window by using this method generates a new process. For more information about protected mode, see Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer. This commonly occurs for applications that host the WebBrowser control."

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "hang" as in "the browser gets completely stalled and I can't even use the toolbars" or as in "the frame/page goes white while I expected it to do something else"?

Have you tried on other IE versions like IE6 or IE8?

Have you tried running the code with popup blocker disabled?

And before blaming the new window... what happens if you try opening a window using the same code but to a different URL such as Google? Does the browser still hang?